# I am not getting the value of my data attributes

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I cannot get the value of the data attribute (data-scd-editUrl) in the following code;

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr data-pkey="@item.TradeId">
         <td style="text-align:left;vertical-align:top;height:20px;">
        <div style="width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden;">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TradeName)
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="rowControl hidden" style="text-align:left;vertical-align:top;height:20px;">
         <div style="width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden;">
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/Pencil.ico")" style="height:15px;width:15px" title="edit" alt="edit" class="makeRowEditable"
                data-scd-editUrl="@Url.Action("Edit", new { id = item.TradeId})"/> |
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/icon-delete.gif")" style="height:15px;width:15px" title="delete" alt="delete" class="deleteRow"
                data-scd-editUrl="@Url.Action("Delete", new { id = item.TradeId})"/>            
         </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

The Jquery is;

```
gridContext.delegate('.makeRowEditable', 'click', function (e) {
    var editUrl = $('this').data("scd-editUrl");
    var row = $(this).parents('tr');
    makeRowEditable(row, editUrl);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The delegate is used because the this code is a row of a grid and is dynamically reloaded for a new page via Ajax.
I put a breakpoint in the above code and editUrl is null.
Why would that be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this

```
  .. data-scd-editurl=...
              //--^---here  

  >>$('this')
  var editUrl = $('this').data("scd-editurl"); //here
```

should be

```
  >>$(this)
   var editUrl = $(this).data("scd-editurl"); //here
```

the data attributes should not contain any upperCase letter.. [link](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes) to read more about it

better way..

```
gridContext.delegate('.makeRowEditable', 'click', function (e) {
  var $this=$(this),
      editUrl = $this.data("scd-editurl"),
      row = $this.parents('tr');

  makeRowEditable(row, editUrl);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I should have known about the syntax of this. But the casing of data attributes was something I did not know about. It seems odd to me but from now on easy to remember. Thank you also for the tip on how to write the jquery properly.

Answer (score 5):

The naming convention of HTML5 data-* attributes is the following:

```
data-scd-edit-url
```

and then:

```
$(this).data('scd-edit-url')
```

If you don't want to respect the convention then you cannot use the `.data()` method. Use the `.attr()` method instead:

```
$(this).attr('data-scd-editUrl')
```

Also notice that `$('this')` should obviously be `$(this)`.

---

UPDATE:

As pointed out in the comments section you could also use the following selector:

```
$(this).data('scdEditUrl')
```

with the `data-scd-editUrl` attribute.

Comment: you may want to add the [link](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes) to the specification.

Comment: `$(this).data('scdEditUrl')` is for retrieving `data-scd-edit-url`, not `data-scd-editUrl` :) In second case, it won't work

Answer (score 0):

Remove `'` and you can also make it as

```
var editUrl = $(this).attr("data-scd-editUrl");
```